# Promise.all not working with an array of async functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Consider the following code which print messages to console after I/O operations complete, in theory.

```
const foo = (num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000)); // An async I/O function in actual code
array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] , [1, 2, 3]];

const promiseArray = array.map(arr => {
  arr.map(num => {
    return (async () => {
      await foo(num);
      console.log(num);
    });
  });
}).flat();

await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work. Nothing was printed to the console.

---

However it would work if I wrap the async function within a Promise constructor

```
const foo = (num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000)); // An async I/O function in actual code
array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] , [1, 2, 3]];

const promiseArray = array.map(arr => {
  arr.map(num => {
    return new Promise(async () => {
      await foo(num);
      console.log(num);
    });
  });
}).flat();

await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

How should I rewrite the code to get rid of the Promise constructor?

Comment: Two problems: 1. in the first callback you don't return anything, so `promiseArray` is just `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. 2. Even if you put a `return`, you aren't returning *promises* but an array of async functions. You have to *execute them* to get promises.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises as its argument, not an array of `async function`s. Also you were missing a `return` statement. You should write

```
const promiseArray = array.flatMap(arr => {
  return arr.map(async num => {
    await foo(num);
    console.log(num);
  });
});

await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

or

```
const promiseArray = array.map(async arr => {
  await Promise.all(arr.map(async num => {
    await foo(num);
    console.log(num);
  }));
});

await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Doesn't the following expression create an async function instead of a Promise?
async num => {
    await foo(num);
    console.log(num);
  }

Comment: @Max Yes, and `map`  calls that async function, mapping the `arr` to an array of promises.

Comment: Can I see it as the following statement?
arr.map((i) => (async num => { await foo(num); console.log(num); })(i))

Comment: @Max Yes, but using an IIFE there is rather pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Its normal Promise.all take an array of Promises, async function are of type function, but returns a Promise once invoked if no explicite return it will return a resolved promise with undefined value.

```js
async function myAsyncFunction(){
  return 1; 
}

console.log(typeof myAsyncFunction)
console.log(typeof myAsyncFunction())
console.log(myAsyncFunction() instanceof Promise)
```

Comment: It's 4 am now and your answer become a clue to my current issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a function from map callback, not a promise. instead return `foo(num)`. then after flattening you have an array of promises.

```
const foo = (num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000)); // An async I/O function in actual code
array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] , [1, 2, 3]];

const promiseArray = array.map(arr => {
  return arr.map(foo); // its equal arr.map(num => foo(num));
}).flat();

const results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
results.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: How about the console.log statement? If I need to include more statements in the async function, how should I code it?

Comment: you can do it easily. as in one of the comments and Brunos answer mentioned, an async function should return a promise. you can do whatever you like and return a promise at the end(the job you did not do). and another problem is that you have to return `arr.map(num => {` (as I mentioned as a comment to Brunos answer)

Comment: even if you do not return a promise from an async function, whatever you return will be wrapped in a `Promise.resolve`(promisified)  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

An **async** function must return a promise. Your first implementation needs a return Statement:

```
const array = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] , [1, 2, 3]];

const promiseArray = array.map(arr => {
  // returning the mapped list
  return arr.map(async (num) => {
    const result = await foo(num);
    console.log('Num: ' + num);
    // return at the end of async will generate a promise fulfillment for you.
    // see: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions
    return result;
  });
}).flat();

const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Comment: You should return `arr.map(num => {` in order to make a 2D array and then flattening it.

Comment: Now this is still not producing an array of promises but an array of async functions.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in my answer too, good point @VLAZ

Comment: An async function always returns a promise. Whether you use the promise declaration or not. See: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#async_return_values

Comment: It returns a promise just if it's called, there is no invocation here, just a declaration

Comment: you guys were right. the the async function wasn't being invoked.